# How to associate the right variable to $_SESSION array on a for each loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this `foreach` loop and when I click the button on the final of each table, I want to put the variables associated with the table on `$_SESSION` array.

How do I do that?

I'm getting data from the database and then I display it on a view. Each row of the table that I am getting data from is displayed on a single bootstrap table. The thing is, in the end of every table I have a button to delete the row from the database associated with the data of the table above. However, when I click on a button (does not matter which button it is), every time is deleted the data from the last table. I can understand why. Just can't make it delete the row that I want.

Here is the code:

```
    foreach ($interesses as $linha)
            {
                $area = $linha["AREA"];
                $atuacao = $linha["GRUPO_ATUACAO"];
                $disponibilidade= $linha["DISPONIBILIDADE"];
                $aano = $linha["ALTURA_ANO"];

                $container = '"container"';
                $table = '"table"';

                $post = '"post"';  

                $utf = '"utf-8"';

                echo "<div class=".$container.">";



                 $_SESSION['area'] = $area;
                 $_SESSION['atuacao'] = $atuacao;
                 $_SESSION['disponibilidade'] = $disponibilidade;
                 $_SESSION['aano'] = $aano;

                 echo "<table class=".$table.">";
                 echo "<thead>";
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<th></th>";
                 echo "<th></th>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "</thead>";
                  echo "<tbody>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><h4>Area de interesse<h4></td>";
                  echo "<td><h4>".$area."</td></h4>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><h4>Grupo de atua&ccedil;&atilde;o<h4></td>";
                  echo "<td><h4>".$atuacao."</td></h4>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><h4>Disponibilidade<h4></td>";
                  echo "<td><h4>".$disponibilidade."</td></h4>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><h4>Epoca do ano<h4></td>";
                  echo "<td><h4>".$aano."</td></h4>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  echo "</thead>";
                  echo "</table>";

                  $hiper = "Apagarinteresse";
                  $button = '"io"';


                echo "<a href=".site_url($hiper)." class=".$button."/>Apagar interesse</a>";



                echo "</div>";

                echo "<br></br>";
```

Comment: can you show the code which perform delete operation

Comment: I think a much easier answer is to not use session at all but to have the button click return the table name and the row number.

Answer (score 0):

You have make separate array for each session variable in foreach loop

```
foreach ($interesses as $linha)
{
// code

$_SESSION['area'][] = $area;
$_SESSION['atuacao'][] = $atuacao;
$_SESSION['disponibilidade'][] = $disponibilidade;
$_SESSION['aano'][] = $aano;

// code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($interesses as $linha)
{
    $area               = $linha["AREA"];
    $atuacao            = $linha["GRUPO_ATUACAO"];
    $disponibilidade    = $linha["DISPONIBILIDADE"];
    $aano               = $linha["ALTURA_ANO"];

    $newdata[] = array(
       'area'  => '$area',
       'atuacao'  => '$atuacao',
       'disponibilidade'  => '$disponibilidade',
       'aano'  => '$aano'
    );

    # Table code
}

# after forloop set the session 
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Comment: It does not work. Same thing. it deletes the last table data. and im getting this error: Message: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller that makes use of $_SESSION:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Apagarinteresse extends CI_Controller {


function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();


$this->load->library('Form_validation');
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->model('apagarinteresse_model');
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->model('perfilvoluntario_model');
$this->load->model('mostrainteresse_model');




}

function index(){

$this->apaga_interesse($this->session->area, $this->session->atuacao, $this-     >session->disponibilidade, $this->session->aano);

}


function apaga_interesse($area, $atuacao, $disponibilidade, $aano){



$data['erro_login'] = "";




    $this->apagarinteresse_model->apaga_interesse($area, $atuacao , $disponibilidade, $aano ,$this->session->email);

    $query = $this->mostrainteresse_model->get_interesses($this->session->email);

    $data['interesses'] = $query->result_array();
    $this->load->view("view_interesses", $data);

    echo '<script>
            alert("Interesse apagado!Confirme abaixo.");
        </script>';



   }





  }

?>
```